# .Net Framework 4.7 calling .net standard 2.0 dll but getting the following error

Tags: .net, .net-standard

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform

I have included the `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` on the .net standard project, but getting this exception. need help.

Comment: A .NET Standard project should not use `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`, which goes against the design of that project type. Move relevant code out, and merge them in your .NET Framework project.

Comment: in that case how do you move a data access layer component that uses oledb to .net standard? typically a data access layer (DAL) component is at the bottom.

Comment: You should not. OldDb is strictly Windows only, then why bother .NET Standard?